# Exponential boundedness of a strongly continuous semigroup $(T_t)_{t>0}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras, semigroup-of-operators

Let $T = (T_t)_{t>0} $ be a strongly continuous semigroup (of bounded operators) on a Banach space $E$, i.e, $ \lim_{t \rightarrow z} \|T_tx- T_{z}x \|, \forall z >0, \forall x \in E $. Note that we **do not** assume strong continuity of $T$ at 0 and neither do we define $T(0)$. Let
$$ w_0:= \inf_{t>0} \frac{\ln\|T_t \|}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln\|T_t \|}{t} < \infty.$$

We call $w_0 \in [-\infty, +\infty)$ the type of $T$. Then for $w > w_0$ there exists $M_w$ such that

$$ \| T_t\| \leq M_w e^{wt}, \quad \forall t> 0 \quad (*)$$

This is Theorem 1.5.9 (page 18) in the book "Theory of semigroups and applications"- Sinha & Srivastava. The authors claim that we can find $t_0$ big enough such that

$$ \| T_t \| \leq e^{wt}, \quad \forall t > t_0.  \quad (1.19) $$

This part, I can understand, then they said the fact that $t \mapsto \| T_t\|$ is bounded on any compact interval in $(0,\infty)$ (Lemma 1.5.3, page 14) together with (1.19) imply the existence of the number $M_w$ in $(*)$, but I don't see how it's done.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Strongly-continuous_semi-group says that under your assumptions, "The behavior of a strongly-continuous semi-group as $t\to0$
 can be completely irregular."

Comment: @dsh That is a very helpful link! However, I still dont understand what  "power singularity" (at $t=0$) is in the sentence that follows the one in your comment in the link. Would you mind explain it to me here?

Comment: I found there an explanation: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Semi-group_of_operators#Semi-groups_with_power_singularities.

Comment: It looks like you need to check if some restricted version of semigroup is assumed in the book...